# showing category and sub categories php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
mysql_select_db($database_test2, $test2);
$query_Recordset1 = "Select   color.name As color,   item.name As Item,   typ.name As Typ,   color.id From   color Inner Join   item On color.id = item.color_id Inner Join   typ On typ.id = item.typ_id Group By   item.name, typ.name, color.id Order By   color.id, typ.name, item.name";
$Recordset1 = mysql_query($query_Recordset1, $test2) or die(mysql_error());
$row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1);
$totalRows_Recordset1 = mysql_num_rows($Recordset1);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<p><?php echo $row_Recordset1['color']; ?>
</p>
<p><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Typ']; ?></p>
<?php do { ?>
  <p><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Item']; ?></p>
  <?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_free_result($Recordset1);
?>
```

i used the above code and  gives this output which is not what i want to have

green

metal

item 1

item 2

item 3

item 4

item 5

item 6

i would like to have it like this

green

metal

.item 1
wood

.item 2

yelow

metal

.item3

wood

.item 4

red

metal

.item5

wood

.item 6

can someone be kind to help me

thanx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your do... while loop you print only the item. Do you have any reason to use do..while instead of while loop?

This should work:

```
<body>
<?php while ( $row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1) ) { ?>
   <p><?php echo $row_Recordset1['color']; ?></p>
   <p><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Typ']; ?></p>
   <p><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Item']; ?></p>
   <?php } ?>
</body>
```

And you will also have to remove the first `mysql_fetch_assoc`, which is before `mysql_num_rows`.

EDIT: Sorry the requirements were not clear when the text was all in one line.
Since you get the rows ordered by color, you can output a color only if it
is different from the previous:

```
<body>
<?php 
$color = '';
while ( $row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1) ) {
   if ( $color != $row_Recordset1[ 'color' ]; ) {
       ?><p><?php echo $row_Recordset1['color']; ?></p><?php
       $color = $row_Recordset1[ 'color' ];
   }
   ?><p><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Typ']; ?></p>
   <p><?php echo $row_Recordset1['Item']; ?></p>
   <?php } ?>
</body>
```

Comment: using the above code it repeats the color value like            green

metal

item 1

green

wood

item 2

Comment: Please help with the above code the out put includes the code itself